# conceptual backbone nested collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am using backbone with Node and Express.  I have my restful api set up to return my model and collection data.  The api works fine.  But I'm having trouble binding a route to one of my api paths.

I have a company model and collection so that when go to the routes you get the restful api data for that route:

`http://localhost:3000/employees` you get the data for restful api path `api/employees`
`http://localhost:3000/employees/1` you get the data for restful api path `api/employees/1`

I also have a category model and collection to do the same:

`http://localhost:3000/categories` you get the data for restful api path `api/categories`

but the following does not work:
`http://localhost:3000/categories/Auto` you don't get the data for restful api path `api/cateogries/Auto` The restful api works and returns the right data, but the collection I get in my app returns the same data as the category collection called with the path `api/cateogries`.  Almost like the path gets ignored.

Typically you have a collection and then you provide a id attribute to get a model that belongs to that collection.  But what if you want a collection whose id attribute returns another collection?  For example, you get a list of categories and then when you select a category you get a list of all the companies in that category?  What is the right way to do this in backbone?

Comment: Can you post some code meanwhile check out if [this](http://backbonerelational.org/) or [this](https://github.com/afeld/backbone-nested) is of any help to you

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured it out.  I was returning a collection and needed to adust the url of my collection to point it to the correct path in my restful api. So in my collection I added a url function that goes to a different route if a parameter is passed into the constructore:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I actually figured it out.  I was returning a collection and needed to adust the url of my collection to point it to the correct path in my restful api. So in my collection I added a url function that goes to a different route if a parameter is passed into the constructor:

```
url:function(){
        if(this.category1){
            return "api/categories/"+this.category1;
        }
        return "api/categories";
      },

    initialize:function(opts){
        this.category1=opts && opts.category1;
    }
```